# Infinite-loop when reading from a text file

Tags: c, file, newline, infinite-loop, fgetc

I have read several questions on this site and managed to write the code below which reads data from a file (shown before the code, below). The problem is that the code gets in an infinite loop in the `do {...} while` segment, indicating that it does not "recognise" the newline char. I have no idea what to do. Also when I pass from the command-line the filename to read, it crashes. Could someone please help?

Input File Format:

```
1 3

3 

3 1 23588769 1 2 1 4 

4 9 4788939 3 2 1 2 2 4 5 5 2 3 3 1 4 

3 5 17215766 5 2 1 1 4 5 5 4
```

Code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fp = NULL;
if (argc == 1)
{
     fp = stdin;
}
else  
{
    fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" ) ;
} 
fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" ) ;  
if (fp == NULL) exit(2);   
for(i=0; i<42; i++)
     KEYS_I_HAVE[i]=0;

     fscanf( fp,"%d",&num_start_keys);
fscanf(fp, "%d",&doors);
KEYS_FOR_DOORS = (int*)malloc(doors*sizeof(int));
POINTS = (int*)malloc(doors*sizeof(int));

for(i=0; i<doors; i++)
            {   
                KEYS_FOR_DOORS[i]=0;
                POINTS[i]=0;
            }
MAP = malloc(doors*sizeof(int));

for(i=0; i<43; i++)
                MAP[i] = malloc(43*sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i<doors; i++)
            {
                for (j=0; j<43; j++)
                    MAP[i][j] = 0;
            }


for(i=0; i<(doors+1); i++)          
            {
                j=0;
                if(i==0)
                    {
                        do
                            {
                                fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp);
                                printf("%d",temp);
                                KEYS_I_HAVE[temp]++;
                                a=fgetc(fp);
                            }while(a != '\n');
                    }
                else
                    {
                        do
                            {
                                fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp);

                                if (j==0)
                                        sum += temp;
                                else
                                    {
                                        if (j==1)
                                            KEYS_FOR_DOORS[i-1] = temp;
                                        else
                                            {
                                                if(j==2)
                                                    POINTS[i-1]=temp;
                                                else

                                                    MAP[i-1][temp]++;
                                            }
                                    }
                                a=fgetc(fp);
                                j++;
                                if (feof(fp) ) break;
                            }while( a != '\n'  );
                    }
            }
 fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Two immediate problems: If you don't provide an argument to the program, it still tries to open `argv[1]`. And if you use `stdin` as input you still close the file at the end of the program.

Comment: Other than that, I recommend you use `while (fgets(...) != NULL)` to read lines, and then parse the contents of the line.

Comment: When you have time, please fix the formatting of the code segment, so that the content on Stackoverflow will continue to be of high quality.  Thanks.

Comment: I submitted a fixed formatting of the code for review. Basically, it's the classing tab vs. space issue

Comment: Thanks for the formatting I am new in this and it is going to take me a while to write properly.  Joachim Pileborg can you please give me an example, this is my first program where i have to use files and i am a bit lost at what do you mean...

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is to change all your `a != '\n'` to `a != EOF && a != '\n'`  There are many other fixes that also ought to be made, but that should fix the problem.

As a general rule, you should do `while( (a=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {...}` instead of `do/while`, since it helps avoid this particular error and is far more idiomatic.  Also, do not use `feof` as you are.  The purpose if `feof` is to distinguish between having reached the end of the data and having encountered a read error.  Since you are not dealing with read errors at all in your code, there is no point in invoking `feof`.  (Note that if you do encounter a read error, `feof` will always return false and you will again be in an infinite loop.)

Comment: The think is i used "a != EOF && a != '\n'" and it didn't work it stopped the loop immediately and the feof works without it it never ends...it is quite messed up

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using fgets and then parsing each line. Example:

```
char line[SOME_MAX_SIZE];

while ( fgets(line, SOME_MAX_SIZE, fp) )
{
    some_parse_function(line);
}
```

For your header line it'd be something like:

```
if ( fgets(line, SOME_MAX_SIZE, fp) )
{
    sscanf(line, "%d %d\n", &num_start_keys, &doors);
}
```